# Пропущен Header при компиляции(VS 2010 Express)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Здравствуйте.

Проблема такая:
Имеется:

1. `Main.cpp` - В нем исполняется функция описанная в `Function.cpp`, 
    а так же прописано `#include "Function.h"`
2. `Function.cpp` - В нем лежит описание функции, а так же прописано `#include "Function.h"`
3. `Function.h` - шаблон функции, а так же прописаны `#include <d3d9.h>` и прочие хедеры с описанием типов используемых в функции.

В книге говориться, что все должно работать и это не лишено логики ведь все правильно.
Однако при компиляции выходит `Warning:`
`warning C4627: '#include "Function.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use    c:\visual c projects\Project\Function.cpp`

Думаю переводить не надо. На этапе билда, хеадер с включаемыми библиотеками пропускаеться и это упущение тащит за собой громадную гору ошибок, потому как в функции используются нестандартные типы данных.

**Вопрос:** Почему хеадер не включается в билд и как устранить это досадное недоразумение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> skipped when looking for precompiled header
>
> ---
>
> Visual C++ версии 6.0 и выше предкомпилирует заголовок со стандартным именем — stdafx.h. (Это имя можно изменить опцией компилятора). В IDE мастер создания проектов позволяет выбрать, следует ли использовать предкомпилированные заголовки. При их использовании будет автоматически добавлена опция компилятора /Yu’stdafx.h', а компиляция любого файла, не содержащего #include «stdafx.h», будет остановлена с ошибкой.

Comment: Спасибо) Теперь понятно) А как в VS 2010 позволить использовать предкомпилированые заголовки?

Comment: А, понял, надо включить `Function.h` в `stdafx.h`, спасибо)